# What am I doing wrong with this partial sum formula?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have this series:$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-\frac{7}{4^n})$$

So my strategy is to divide it into two formulas to try and get a geometric formula:$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1 - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{7}{4^n}$$

The first sum equals 1 and I simplify the second sum to a geometric formula:$$1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty 7(\frac{1}{4})^n$$

So I plug that into the formula $\frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$ and end up with$$1-\frac{7(1-(\frac{1}{4})^n)}{1-\frac{1}{4}}$$

I simplify that and get$$1-\frac{28(1-(\frac{1}{4})^n}{3}$$

So that's how I did it but when I type that in my calculator it doesn't match up with the answers I calculated manually. Can somebody tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: The first sum is not $1$, it is infinite. Thus (since the second sum converges) this means that the sum diverges.

Comment: Don't edit toooooooo much. Since this question was first posted, you have edited more than 10 times.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1 = \infty$$
not one.

You can also observe that 
$$\lim_n(1-\frac{7}{4^n})=1 \neq 0$$
therefore, the series is divergent.

Comment: Ahh I confused the sum with a limit. Thank you